# Help with nth-child(), selecting all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I might have missed something completely stupid, but I can't figure this out.

I am working on some simple jquery practice and was looking to select the specified children from an aside element to get the width.  However, when I would select it, the return value was `null`. So I tried a few things, and I switch nth child value to 2 and the method to html() to see if that would do anything and yes infact, when I use nth-child(2) it selects all children in the aside element.

Javascript:

```
var modOneWidth = $('aside:nth-child(1)').width();
console.log(modOneWidth); //returns null

var modOneWidth = $('aside:nth-child(2)').html();
console.log(modOneWidth); //returns html of all children in aside
```

Aside Element and it's children (which are placed in a `<section>` element):

```
        <aside>
            <article>
                <h2>Module 1</h2>
                <p>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Module 2</h2>
                <p>riosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Module 3</h2>
                <p>ipsum dolor sit arud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat.</p>
            </article>
        </aside>
```

Again, can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, can it be HTML5 elements? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there another `<aside>` element that you are not showing us? See [`nth-child(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: I noticed your second variable is named `modOneWidth`, but you're grabbing the `.html()`.  Is this intentional?  **edit: I'm a moron: ignore me.**

Comment: @NimChimpsky: It's one-based.

Comment: oh yeah, oops. the only jquery selector that is ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to select: the `<aside>` element, or its children. Calling `.html()` **does not select anything**. `aside:nth-child(n)` selects the nth `<aside>` child of its parent. It does not select the `<aside>`'s children.

Comment: Don't confuse nth-child with nth-of-type. My guess is that there is a element in front of the aside (inside section element).

Comment: @Nim, that's because the native CSS `:nth-child()` selector is one-based, so jQuery follows the same behavior, even if it's not consistent with its other selectors.

Comment: Duh...wow, it was something completely stupid. I was using nth-child selector on aside. Like a number of you pointed out, I need to do nth-child on aside article...Thanks a lot for the fast and helpful responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're applying the [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector to the `<aside>` elements, so your selector ends up matching the `<aside>` element which is the nth child of its parent.

You should match the `<article>` elements instead:

```
var modOneWidth = $("aside article:nth-child(1)").width();
```

Comment: your absolutely right...Stupid mistake on my part. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('aside').children('article:eq(0)').html();
```